# Paragraph is overflowing in Internet Explorer 11. Chrome and Firefox are fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically creating the paragraphs using JavaScript with from a SP2013 list, but the content is overflowing when using IE11.

I have tried `overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word;
-ms-word-break: break-all;` without any success.

```js
var cyberAware = $('#cyberAware');
var cyberAwareCard;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 cyberAwareCard = '<h2 class="h2-responsive font-weight-bold">' + items[i].Title + '</h2>' +
  '<p>' + items[i].Description + '</p>' +
  '<a class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trophy left"></i> Take the Challenge</a>';
  
  cyberAware.append(cyberAwareCard);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="cyberAware">
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="text-black text-center d-flex align-items-center py-5 px-4 
card cyberAware">
      <div id="cyberAware">
   <!--Injected Code here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Text should remain inside the  not overlflowing.

[IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMEUC.jpg)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyvk1.jpg)

Comment: Have you attempted to remove superfluous CSS like `d-flex` (the Card component is already set to flex)? Specificity might be causing elements of `.d-flex` to conflict with what that component does to child elements.

Comment: @Robert that worked. 
Thanks